# Player asking for a free kick when ref calls advantage

Tags: football, officiating

Recently I played 2 games with the same ref, and both in multiple times in the game me(goalkeeper) came to claim a ball in a un crowded box with my hands, the forward with a very debatable chance at getting the ball, jumps into me after me catching the ball and holding it up, I fall down and expect a kick for the unnecessary challenge, but the ref believes it was a foul but she says she’s playing advantage, mind you the entire offensive team is already back in their half the only advantage is that I’m holding the ball instead of taking a free kick which pushed the team back

the section in laws of the game I am basing my complaint off is under the “other advice” page where it goes over various concepts with a little more detail,

The referee may play advantage whenever an offence occurs but should consider the following in deciding whether to apply the advantage or stop play:

-the severity of the offence – if the offence warrants a sending-off, the referee must stop play and send off the player unless there is a clear opportunity
to score a goal

-the position where the offence was committed – the closer to the opponent’s goal, the more effective the advantage can be

-the chances of an immediate, promising attack

-the atmosphere of the match

Comment: And you're now asking for the right call in such situation?

Comment: @dly yes I’m asking if this is the right decision, because in the Laws of the game it says that the player has no say in how advantage is played, however, the laws also say that advantage is rarely given in the teams own half unless a counterattack or promising chance is available, which it was not

Comment: @JosiahJones could you please [edit in](https://sports.stackexchange.com/posts/29262/edit) (don't comment) the specific wording [_in the Laws_](https://www.theifab.com/laws-of-the-game-documents/?language=all&year=2023%2F24) you are basing your comment on?

Comment: It appears you've said yourself why the referee gave advantage here: the goalkeeper holding the ball is always more favourable than kicking from the ground. They did the best thing they could to help the fouled team, which was, let play continue.

Comment: It appears you misunderstand the laws of the game, or the ways the game is played, a free kick is always a better way to get the ball up the field from a defending teams own half, by forcing the other team to release pressure from the kicker and move back, it also clearly states in the laws of the game that “advantage” which is what you are describing when the referee lets the keeper have the ball, is rarely called in the defending team’s own half, because there is usually no advantage in that part of the pitch, and a free kick would release pressure and move the ball up the pitch easier.